# Sum of a random number of r.v.'s

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, geometric-distribution

A fair coin is flipped independently until the first Heads is observed. Let the random variable  **K**  be the number of tosses until the first Heads is observed plus 1. For example, if we see **TTTHTH**, then **K=5**. For  **k=1,2,…,K** , let  $X_k$   be a continuous random variable that is uniform over the interval  **[0,5]**. The  $X_k$  are independent of one another and of the coin flips.

Let 
X=$\sum_{k=1}^k X_k$
 . Find the mean and variance of  **X** . You may use the fact that the mean and variance of a geometric random variable with parameter  **p**  are  $\frac 1p$and  ${(1−p)\over(p^2)}$ respectively.

1. What is $E[X]$?
2. What is $Var[X]$?

**My solution:**

$E[N] = \frac{1}{p} = 2$

$E[X_k] =\frac{1}{2}\times 5=\frac{5}{2}$

$E[X] = E[N]\times E[X_k]=2\times\frac{5}{2} = 5$

$Var[N]=\frac{(1−p)}{p^2} = 2$

$Var[X_k] = \frac{1}{12}\times 5^2 = \frac{25}{12}$

Comment: Avoid cross-posting: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3291498/321264. Better to choose where you want to ask.

Comment: I saw this question on this site (https://stats.stackexchange.com/) hours ago.

Comment: Please decide which site you want to ask your question on, & delete the other version. Cross-posting is against SE policy & it wastes a lot of people's time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is cross-posted on [math.SE].

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I assume $N=K$ in your solutions. The expected value and variance of $X$ can be found via Law of Iterated Expectation (LIE) and Law of Total Variance (LTV):

$$E[X]=E[E[X|K]], \ \ \ \ \operatorname{var}(X)=E[\operatorname{var(X|K)}]+\operatorname{var}(E[X|K])$$

For the expectation, your approach is correct, but it can be found via LIE:
$$E[X|K]=KE[X_k]\rightarrow E[KE[X_k]]=E[K]E[X_k]$$
You just need to correct your expectation for $K$: $E[K]=1/p+1$, since it is of the form $1+Y$, where $Y$ is a geometric RV with parameter $p$. Also, note that $\operatorname{var}(K)=\operatorname{var}(1+Y)=\operatorname{var}(Y)=(1-p)/p^2$ as yours.

For the variance, we need $\operatorname{var}(X|K)=\operatorname{var}(\sum X_k|K)=K \operatorname{var}(X_k)$, and by LTV:
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{var}(X)&=E[K\operatorname{var}(X_k)]+\operatorname{var}(KE[X_k])\\ &=\operatorname{var}(X_k)E[K]+E[X_k]^2\operatorname{var}(K)\end{align}$$
The rest is substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Formulas for the mean and variance of $X$ are stated and derived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200808171457/http://www.math.unl.edu/%7Esdunbar1/ProbabilityTheory/Lessons/Conditionals/RandomSums/randsum.shtml).
Notice that there are two components to $V(X).$

If you're interested in *distribution* of $X$ you can do a simulation. In R, the a geometric random variable counts the number of failures before the first success;
this is the *second* version in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). With a million iterations one can expect
about 3 significant digits of accuracy.

```
set.seed(712)
x = replicate(10^6,  sum(runif(rgeom(1,.5)+2,0,5)))    
mean(x);  var(x)
[1] 7.497338     # aprx E(X) = 15/2
[1] 18.73797     # aprx V(X) = 75/4
mean(x < 10)
[1] 0.787989     # aprx P(X<10) = 0.788 +/- 0.001 
2*sd(x < 10)/10^3
[1] 0.0008174656 # aprx 95% marg of sim err

hist(x, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main="")
```

[image]